# Excel -Conditional Formatting using Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I have a table of data. Using the following working formula in Conditional formatting, it highlights correctly in red, from top to bottom, the Starting Cell of the group of cells when the formula is True.

```
=COUNTA(D8:D21)-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"OFF")-COUNTIF(Dt8:D21,"Leave")>13
```

However I would like it to highlight in red the last cell in the group. How can this be done. I tried the following with no joy...

```
=If(COUNTA(D8:D21)-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"OFF")-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"Leave")>13, (COUNTA(D8:D21)-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"OFF")-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"Leave")>13)+13, 0)

=Count(D8:D34)+COUNTA(D8:D21)-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"OFF")-COUNTIF(D8:D21,"Leave")>13
```

Comment: Can you show sample data and indicate which cell should be red?

Comment: @user11217663   I need to have atleast one rest day in a 14day period. From the example below, using the above formula, if  I attend the Gym on 17th March it will highlight in red  cell containing "GYM" on the 4th March indicating I have attended Gym too many consecutive days and I need a rest period in between. This is OK but it means I have to continually scroll up to see if any cell turned red as I input new data. I would rather it warn me as I am entering New data, i.e.In this example, highlight the Cell contain GYM on the 17th March  instaed of the 4th March.

Comment: @Harun24HR  
04-Mar M Gym
05-Mar T Gym
06-Mar W Gym
07-Mar T Gym
08-Mar F Gym
09-Mar S Gym
10-Mar S Gym
11-Mar M Gym
12-Mar T Gym
13-Mar W Gym
14-Mar T Gym
15-Mar F Gym
16-Mar S Gym
17-Mar S Gym